# Point iTunes to a folder on a networked machine

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, file-sharing

I have a machine running Ubuntu 9.10 which I use to keep my media on. An external USB hard drive is connected to it that has a folder of music. How would I set it up so that my iTunes running on another machine on the same network can use the music from the hard drive in its library? Also, in general how would I set it up so that any machine on the network can download and upload files from the external hard drive connected to the Ubuntu box?

For iTunes, it would be running on a Mac 10.6. As for general file sharing, the machines would be Mac or Windows XP/7. I would like it to be password protected at least.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. You'd want to set up file sharing (probably using Samba if iTunes is on a windows machine; probably NFS or maybe AFP if you're sharing with a Mac)

Some more detail about what machines you have on your network, and what level of security you want, would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/05/19/how-to-share-files-and-folders-in-ubuntu/ makes it look pretty easy to turn on sharing for a folder in Ubuntu :)

Comment: Good link. You will need to enable both NFS (for Mac OS) and SMB (for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to setup file sharing.

To share with iTunes on Mac, NFS is probably the best solution. You'd want to mount the NFS share on the Mac so you can access it using a local path. See [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22243?viewlocale=en_US) for this.

To share files with Windows, you might want to use Samba instead (or in addition to it). You'll then be able to access it as you would a Windows share in your explorer.